# CUDA 5.0 wants the libcudart from CUDA 4.0?

Tags: cuda, gpu, nvidia, nvcc

I just upgraded from CUDA 4.2 to CUDA 5.0. Not surprisingly, the library that used to be named `libcudart.so.4` is now called `libcudart.so.5.0`. After recompiling my code with nvcc 5.0, and attempting to running the code, I got this message:

```
./main: error while loading shared libraries: libcudart.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Yeah, you stupid system, I know there's no `libcudart.so.4`. That's because it's now called `libcudart.so.5.0`. **Why is it looking for `libcudart.so.4` instead of `libcudart.so.5.0`, and how can I fix it?**

---

What I've tried so far:

I've checked that all my paths are in order. These environment variables are set:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/cuda/bin:/usr/lib
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/cuda/lib:/usr/local/cuda/lib64:/lib
#note: /usr/local/cuda is symlinked to /usr/local/cuda-5.0
```

I've verified that `libcudart.so.5.0` can be found in one of the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` directories.

I recompiled my CUDA application with the the CUDA 5.0 version of `nvcc`. I successfully compiled and ran my application on an other machine with CUDA 4.2, and on an other machine with CUDA 4.0.

I confirmed that `nvcc` is really on version 5.0:

```
user@host$ nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2012 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Fri_Sep_21_17:28:58_PDT_2012
Cuda compilation tools, release 5.0, V0.2.122
```

Comment: Maybe this is obvious, but `nvcc` seems to be statically linking against `libcudart.a` version 4. Maybe that's hiding in your lib path somewhere?

Comment: yup, that's what happened! I just wiped the old display driver and reinstalled it, and it seems to be ok now. Feel free to post your comment as an answer, and I'll accept it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd like to get this question off the unanswered list, and I don't think @Jared Hoberock will mind, so I'm going to post his comment as an answer.  If there's a concern and Jared or solvingPuzzles posts an answer, I'll delete mine (assuming it's not accepted -- I can't delete an accepted answere AFAIK).

`nvcc` seems to be statically linking against `libcudart.a` version 4.

Somewhere in your lib path, it seems that `nvcc` is finding an old `libcudart.a`, which needs to be removed.

For other readers, it's probably just sufficient to find all instances of `libcudart.*` on the system and delete any that don't match your desired CUDA version (assuming you're not trying to run a machine with multiple CUDA versions available -- in that case, the library paths for both compiling and running have to be managed appropriately)

Comment: Yup, this was the problem. I had symlinked a `cuda 4.2` version of `libcudart.a.version -> libcudart.a` in CUDA installation directory. Cleaned up my old symlinks, and all was well. Removing an old display driver version also helped with similar CUDA 4 vs 5 problems.

Comment: I have the same problem where `locate libcudart` gives me `/usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/glnx86/libcudart.so.4
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/glnx86/libcudart.so.4.0.17
/usr/local/cuda-5.5/lib/libcudart.so
/usr/local/cuda-5.5/lib/libcudart.so.5.5
/usr/local/cuda-5.5/lib/libcudart.so.5.5.22
/usr/local/cuda-5.5/lib/libcudart_static.a` how can I solve this conflict with matlab?